# How to remove files and directories quickly via terminal (bash shell)

Tags: file, terminal, directory, rm, rmdir

From a terminal window:

When I use the `rm` command it can only remove files. 
When I use the `rmdir` command it only removes empty folders.

If I have a directory nested with files and folders within folders with files and so on, is there a way to delete all the files and folders without all the strenuous command typing?

If it makes a difference, I am using the Mac Bash shell from a terminal, not Microsoft DOS or Linux.

Comment: Just in case you wish to restore the files in future , don't use "rm" for such cases .  
                Use "rm-trash"  : https://github.com/nateshmbhat/rm-trash

Answer (score 974, accepted):

```
rm -rf some_dir
```

-r "recursive"
-f "force" (suppress confirmation messages)

Be careful!

Comment: +1 and glad you added the "Be careful!" part... definitely a "Sawzall" command that can quickly turn a good day into a bad one.. if wielded carelessly.

Comment: like dont do  
"# rm -rf /"
you ll regret that:

Comment: @itsmatt: You know what they say...give someone a Sawzall, and suddenly every problem looks like hours of fun!

Comment: On a Mac? Do this instead: `brew install trash` then `trash -rf some_dir` This will move the unwanted directory into your trashbin instead of just vanishing _Prestige_-style into the ether. ([source](http://hasseg.org/trash/))

Comment: I get "Permission denied"

Comment: If you get "Permission denied" use `sudo rm -rf some_dir`

Comment: Error: Cowardly refusing to 'sudo brew install'
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.

Comment: To remove many directory with the same name (in this case .wdmc) recursively, go
find . -iname ".wdmc" -exec rm -rfv {} +

Comment: make sure you are not in a modified interactive bash session as it might lead to a different outcome

Answer (score 89):

```
rm -rf *
```

Would remove everything (folders & files) in the current directory.

**But be careful!** Only execute this command if you are absolutely sure, that you are in the right directory.

Comment: rm -rf is very risky command, you should always be careful and specify  folder to be deleted.

Comment: How about running `ls -R *` first to see what will be deleted by `rm -rf *`

Comment: This works fine for me, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, there is.  The `-r` option tells `rm` to be **r**ecursive, and remove the entire file hierarchy rooted at its arguments; in other words, if given a directory, it will remove all of its contents and then perform what is effectively an `rmdir`.

The other two options you should know are `-i` and `-f`.  `-i` stands for **i**nteractive; it makes `rm` prompt you before deleting each and every file.  `-f` stands for **f**orce; it goes ahead and deletes everything without asking.  `-i` is safer, but `-f` is faster; only use it if you're *absolutely sure* you're deleting the right thing.  You can specify these with `-r` or not; it's an independent setting.

And as usual, you can combine switches: `rm -r -i` is just `rm -ri`, and `rm -r -f` is `rm -rf`.

Also note that what you're learning applies to `bash` on every Unix OS: OS X, Linux, FreeBSD, etc.  In fact, `rm`'s syntax is the same in pretty much *every shell* on every Unix OS.  OS X, under the hood, is really a BSD Unix system.

Comment: Although all the options mentioned above are standard among all the Unix flavors listed, there are some differences too. For example, OS X (but not Linux) has `"rm -d"`, which removes either files or empty directories. Still, +1 for the point that OS X is BSD internally.

Comment: True---the *POSIX subset* is (pretty much) guaranteed to work consistently across Unixen, but anything outside that may or may not.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a way to remove all files in a directory except for some directories, and files, I wanted to keep around. I devised a way to do it using *[find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix))*:

```
find -E . -regex './(dir1|dir2|dir3)' -and -type d -prune -o -print -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Essentially it uses regex to select the directories to exclude from the results then removes the remaining files.