# Xcode 6.1 - How to uninstall command line tools?

Tags: xcode, command-line-tool

I installed Xcode command line tool by issuing `xcode-select --install`; now I want to uninstall it (without uninstalling Xcode).

I've tried

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

but then I get the error

```
sudo: /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools: command not found
```

Comment: I believe your `$PATH` is messed up? What's the output when you type `which sudo` or `whereis sudo`? Hopefully it prints something like `/usr/bin/sudo`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014588-CH1-HOW_DO_I_UNINSTALL_MY_COMMAND_LINE_TOOLS_

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308943/how-do-i-uninstall-the-command-line-tools-for-xcode

Answer (score 99):

If you installed the command line tools separately, delete them using:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: sudo rm -r CommandLineTools is enough, force here you need don't

Comment: Then, `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`

Answer (score 55):

An excerpt from an apple [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html) (Thanks to [matthias-bauch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457406/))

> Xcode includes all your command-line tools. If it is installed on your
>   system, *remove* it to uninstall your tools.
>
> If your tools were downloaded separately from Xcode, then they are
>   located at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` on your system. *Delete
>   the CommandLineTools* folder to uninstall them.

you could easily [**delete using terminal**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2642147/730807):

Here is an [article](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/you-dont-need-the-xcode-command-line-tools/) that explains how to remove the command line tools but do it at your own risk.Try this only if any of the above doesn't work.

Comment: Which OS are you using ? Try this on terminal `cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`  If you get `No such file or directory` then the path is not there for sure.

Comment: I am able to access it. I think the link is blocked by firewall or something

Comment: What's more important, removing this directory doesn't let ```xcode-select --install``` work

Comment: @Jason I moved/renamed the directory and the xcode-select --install worked just fine

Answer (score 7):

You can simply delete this folder

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

**Please note: This is the root /Library, not user's ~/Library).**

Comment: No - that doesn't do it... removed the directory... command still works.

Comment: Seems your command line tools are not installed separately, and it is installed through Xcode.