# How to uninstall Xcode 6 and remove all related files

Tags: xcode, uninstallation

I need to completely reinstall Xcode 6 and remove all the files and settings with it.

I know that it is uninstalled so that you go to mission control, long click on it and then click on the X button, like on iPhone.

I also know that you can drag it to trash from applications.

But after all those, when I install it again through AppStore and open the last project I was working on, Xcode will open the project on exactly the same class where i t was shut down and even show the last error I faced!

I don't want that. That means that some User Preferences are still saved somewhere and I want to get rid of them as I have never ever had Xcode installed on my Mac.

How to do that?

Comment: It's now related to programming...

Comment: I don't see how Xcode is different to any other app, so use [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/).

Comment: Even though you might not like it, @David'mArm'Ansermot is completely right. This is the wrong site to ask for uninstalling Mac applications. You should go to *AskDifferent* (a *StackExchange* site as well.) And for being rude you may get flagged if you wish.

Comment: I have a programming issue which is related to Xcode. So uninstalling Xcode and all of it file will solve it, so it pretty much makes it programming question

Comment: It's not about programming probleme but software for programming probleme. It's not the same ;).

Comment: I do not quite get what the fuss is about @LinusG. From the help section: "a specific programming problem, **or** a software algorithm, **or** software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". And yes, it is bewildering that an important tool like Xcode is so notoriously hard to remove thoroughly...

Comment: Moreover, quite similar questions are known to be highly uprooted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438457/xcode-6-1-how-to-uninstall-command-line-tools

Comment: You see, the question is not related to programming. Now you claim it is about programming tools which also lets it fit to SO but there simply is a site that fits **even better**: Ask Different. It's just like in a english test, you have to choose whichever fits *best*.

Comment: Well... the votes on other, quad identical questions such as the one cited seem to give some indication that such questions are not out of place so I beg to differ (unless all those uprooters are wrong too). Anyway, there was no reason to down vote this question IMO

Answer (score -1):

You can use several uninstall programs like you would uninstall any other Mac application.

So some examples might be *App Cleaner* or *Clean My Mac*.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Really? Some at best 'shady' if not potentially dubious 3rd party tools (one of them paying) to remove something like Xcode? There have to be better ways

Comment: Dubious? I don't think so. They are a solution since there is no official uninstaller. I'm using CleanMyMac for years now, never had any issues, always worked great.

Comment: Well... I just tried the 3.0 beta of App Cleaner: what it seems to do is a rather 'dumb' string search for 'xcode' and it doesn't really find anything other than Xcode.app and some random plist files whereas it completely misses /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator or /Library/Developer/Xcode for that matter... So I am very skeptical about the quality of these solutions...

Comment: You say you tried the **beta**...get it? A **beta**! Again, try Clean My Mac. Works great.

Comment: Seriously... yes I have used a beta but that doesn't change the basic MO of any of the tools you mentioned. They do "dumb" string searches for anything that closely resembles the name of the program you try to remove. The stable versions of the tool I tried acted no different and neither did Clean my Mac (a paying "solution" no less). These tools are _never_ a solution: a good answer to the (very valid) original question would consist of a listing of affected directories, locations where xcode installer puts things, i.e. the real programmers solution, not some random tool...

Comment: You gave the asker comments on posing a "non dev" question that would be better suited elsewhere and yet you give a decidedly "non dev" answer. That is my issue. But OK, let's agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: There is no hate, none at all. I was struck by the tone of your comments to the original question which also came across as a bit pedantic "being rude will get you flagged". That is not constructive. Then you proceed to advise some tools which give users with limited knowledge a false sense of "solution" while with a little more effort you could have provided more in depth answers. Because all being said, none of the tools managed to remove all of Xcode in my local testing. That is all... again, really no hate but correct is correct...

Comment: Who says correct? I always deinstalled Xcode with CmM and it always worked just fine. Obviously it worked for OP as well since he accepted my answer. If you think there should be a better answer, then post one yourself :)

Comment: Then I would like you to define "worked fine": It is a matter of fact that e.g. all the device emulation gets missed by these tools  e.g. /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator . The fact that the answer is accepted says nothing. If the guy did not care to check, how could he know it worked beyond just appearing to have worked? Anyway, I think you are just trolling. Move along now... nothing to see here.

Comment: Alright, since I did not really care about those folders you might be right, there probably is a better solution. But instead of entitling my a troller and spreading your hate you could simply explain why my answer is insufficient and share a better one. That would even help people, including me and OP. :)