# svn: error: unable to find utility svn, not a developer tool or in PATH Mac OS 10.10.4

Tags: xcode, macos, svn

When I try running just 'svn' in terminal I get this error:

xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk/" cannot be located.
svn: error: unable to find utility "svn", not a developer tool or in PATH

If I run "which svn" it comes back with /usr/bin/svn.

I'm running xcode 6.4 with latest command line tools installed.  No idea why I'm getting an error mentioning iPhoneOS4.1.sdk as that's ancient history.

xcode-select -p reports:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

All suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suffered the same problem and managed to resolve it; but I'm not quite sure what did the trick.

First I (re?-)installed command line tools for x-tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

and then I clicked Install when prompted. This did not help at first, but after a reboot the problem was gone.

Comment: sadly I end up with the error `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

Comment: nevermind, I had to first [delete](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29859370/1373278) then reinstall