# i386 arch error installing old scrypt gem version with OS X Mojave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compiler-errors, rubygems

I'm trying to install an old gem version for an old project after a fresh install of OS X 10.14 Mojave and XCode Command Line Tools. The gem I'm trying to install is scrypt, version 1.2.1, which is a dependency of authlogic.

gem install scrypt -v=1.2.1

Returns the following error:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing scrypt:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@rails5/gems/scrypt-1.2.1/ext/scrypt
/Users/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/bin/ruby -rrubygems /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@rails5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.4.0/scrypt-1.2.1 RUBYLIBDIR=/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@rails5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.4.0/scrypt-1.2.1
mkdir -p x86_64-darwin
gcc -fexceptions -O -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -msse -msse2 -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -o x86_64-darwin/crypto_scrypt-sse.o -c ./crypto_scrypt-sse.c
gcc -fexceptions -O -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -msse -msse2 -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -o x86_64-darwin/memlimit.o -c ./memlimit.c
gcc -fexceptions -O -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -msse -msse2 -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -o x86_64-darwin/scrypt_calibrate.o -c ./scrypt_calibrate.c
gcc -fexceptions -O -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -msse -msse2 -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -o x86_64-darwin/scrypt_ext.o -c ./scrypt_ext.c
gcc -fexceptions -O -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -msse -msse2 -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -o x86_64-darwin/scryptenc_cpuperf.o -c ./scryptenc_cpuperf.c
gcc -fexceptions -O -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -msse -msse2 -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -o x86_64-darwin/sha256.o -c ./sha256.c
gcc -bundle -o x86_64-darwin/libscrypt_ext.bundle x86_64-darwin/crypto_scrypt-sse.o x86_64-darwin/memlimit.o x86_64-darwin/scrypt_calibrate.o x86_64-darwin/scrypt_ext.o x86_64-darwin/scryptenc_cpuperf.o x86_64-darwin/sha256.o -fexceptions -arch x86_64 -arch i386 
ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "___error", referenced from:
      _crypto_scrypt in crypto_scrypt-sse.o
      _memtouse in memlimit.o
  "___stack_chk_fail", referenced from:
      _scrypt_SHA256_Transform in sha256.o
      _scrypt_SHA256_Final in sha256.o
      _HMAC_scrypt_SHA256_Init in sha256.o
      _HMAC_scrypt_SHA256_Final in sha256.o
      _PBKDF2_scrypt_SHA256 in sha256.o
  "___stack_chk_guard", referenced from:
      _scrypt_SHA256_Transform in sha256.o
      _scrypt_SHA256_Final in sha256.o
      _HMAC_scrypt_SHA256_Init in sha256.o
      _HMAC_scrypt_SHA256_Final in sha256.o
      _PBKDF2_scrypt_SHA256 in sha256.o
  "_free", referenced from:
      _crypto_scrypt in crypto_scrypt-sse.o
  "_getrlimit$UNIX2003", referenced from:
      _memtouse in memlimit.o
  "_gettimeofday", referenced from:
      _scryptenc_cpuperf in scryptenc_cpuperf.o
  "_malloc", referenced from:
      _crypto_scrypt in crypto_scrypt-sse.o
  "_memcpy", referenced from:
      _scrypt_SHA256_Update in sha256.o
      _PBKDF2_scrypt_SHA256 in sha256.o
  "_mmap$UNIX2003", referenced from:
      _crypto_scrypt in crypto_scrypt-sse.o
  "_munmap$UNIX2003", referenced from:
      _crypto_scrypt in crypto_scrypt-sse.o
  "_sysconf", referenced from:
      _memtouse in memlimit.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [gcc -bundle -o x86_64-darwin/libscrypt_ext...]
/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@rails5/gems/ffi-compiler-1.0.1/lib/ffi-compiler/compile_task.rb:153:in `block in define_task!'
/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => default => x86_64-darwin/libscrypt_ext.bundle
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was experiencing this exact problem.

I'm running Mojave (10.14.4) and Version 10.2 of the XCode Command Line Tools, and when running `gem install scrypt -v 1.2.1`, I was getting the exact same error as described above.

The solution was to install this package:  `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` (as described in [Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave)).  Apparently the root of the issue was that somewhere in this process (bundler? scrypt?) there was an expectation that header files could be found in `/usr/include`.  The latest version of XCode does not place header files in that location,  but running the package places them there (as documented in  [the XCode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes))

Answer (score 4):

Installing the [command line tools for 10.13](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10.1.dmg) fixed this for me.

Comment: This concept worked for me but the link did not. I had to sign in and navigate through a list to find 10.13.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the i386 architecture is deprecated & removed for the newest version of macOS. There are still at least 2 options that might work for you, assuming you're unable to upgrade your `scrypt` version (which is probably the best option)

- Use a docker image. I just tested with `ruby:2.5.3-slim`, and you only need to run `apt-get update && apt-get build-essential && gem install scrypt -v 1.2.1`
- Download the older SDK, which includes the i386 architecture, and install it on your system. [This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22598) has some links and info that might be useful (though not rails-specific)

Comment: Do you know the latest SDK that includes the i386 arch? Have you encountered any issues running and older SDK on OS X 10.14 Mojave? Thanks so much for the reply!

Comment: @gominimal I haven't actually tried the older SDK but the link I posted seems to indicate it works fine. Personally I'd worry about it potentially causing other issues now or in the future so I would opt for a docker image to isolate. That's a pretty old dependency to downgrade an SDK for IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the versions of answers given, it did not exactly do the job for me. Then the following steps worked for me.

First check if the header files are present.

```
ls /usr/include
ls: /usr/include: No such file or directory
```

As the headers were not present, I removed CommandLineTools, like given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29859370/2076529)

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Update xcode and install the macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg

```
xcode-select --install
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Now the header files were present when I did
`ls /usr/include`

`gem install scrypt -v 1.2.1`