# Trying to install rails, but I get the error "i386 architecture is deprecated on macOS."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

**[The full text of the error](https://textuploader.com/d8aj5)**

The most important line, to my untrained eye, seems to be: `ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)`
But am I really supposed to modify the Xcode build settings?

I am trying `$ sudo gem install rails`.

**My specs:**
macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
Xcode version: 10.0 (10A255)
Ruby version: 2.3.7p456
Gem version: 2.7.8

**Recommendations I've found so far:**
1) Install xcode command line tools. They are installed.
2) `bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries`.
/\ I've read that I should not do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don’t use system Ruby. Install Ruby with RVM, then retry `gem install rails`.

Comment: Thank you. Should I remove this question? Does leaving it up help the next person? And is there a reason you didn't post a reply rather than a comment?

Comment: Because I make the same comment several times a week on nearly identical questions. The answer is always: [don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/), and short/glib responses are better suited to comments.

Comment: Going forward, never post your error message by supplying a link to an external website. Post it **here**, in your question. Links die; external sites may be blocked; etc.

Comment: @anothermh so do you have a dupe to flag against?

Comment: I could find dozens of questions where the gist is "I'm having trouble installing a gem with system Ruby" but I'm not sure it's worth the time to look for even one. The answer is simple: don't use system Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @anothermh mentioned, you shouldn't use system ruby. I'd mention further that you don't want to, and shouldn't need to, run `sudo` to install gems.

Use a ruby version manager such as [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) (my recommended), rvm (probably one of the most popular), or rbenv (also a solid choice).

I'd also recommend, if you haven't done it already, that you grab homebrew because you'll need a few dependencies. Highly recommend at least:

```
brew install gcc libxml2 readline
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to bundle install and had issue like this. In my case upgrading rails from 4.2.5. to 4.2.9 fixed error. Maybe it will help someone to not lose time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528115/i386-arch-error-installing-old-scrypt-gem-version-with-os-x-mojave - this will work for Mojave