# How to Install Rails on MAC: Error Installing Rails on MAC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I am trying to set Rails on my MAC, but continue to get an error even with all the previous help provided by people that have also faced the same problem.

I downloaded Ruby 2.4.1 using rbenv and now I need to install rails 4.2.1 but I continue to get the following error.

ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
Fetching actionview-4.2.1.gem
Fetching actionpack-4.2.1.gem
Fetching railties-4.2.1.gem
Fetching activejob-4.2.1.gem
Fetching actionmailer-4.2.1.gem
Fetching activemodel-4.2.1.gem
Fetching activerecord-4.2.1.gem
Fetching rails-4.2.1.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.3/ext/nokogiri
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0 -r ./siteconf20190527-36261-6oqyvd.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts  -I     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libxml2... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.4.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.9
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Do-not-URI-escape-in-server-side-includes.patch
    - 0002-Remove-script-macro-support.patch
    - 0003-Update-entities-to-remove-handling-of-ssi.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.9.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin17/ports/libxml2/2.9.9... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.3/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Do-not-URI-escape-in-server-side-includes.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.3/patches/libxml2/0002-Remove-script-macro-support.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.3/patches/libxml2/0003-Update-entities-to-remove-handling-of-ssi.patch... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.9... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.9... ERROR, review '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.3/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64 apple-darwin17/ports/libxml2/2.9.9/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
  CC       testdso.lo
  CCLD     testdso.la
  CC       xmllint.o
  CCLD     xmllint
ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.4/lib/liblzma.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.4/lib/liblzma.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_lzma_auto_decoder", referenced from:
      _xz_head in libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
  "_lzma_code", referenced from:
      _xz_decomp in libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
  "_lzma_end", referenced from:
      ___libxml2_xzclose in libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
  "_lzma_properties_decode", referenced from:
      _is_format_lzma in libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [xmllint] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.4.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:402:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.4.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:373:in `chdir'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.4.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:373:in `execute'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.4.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:115:in `compile'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.4.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:154:in `cook'
from extconf.rb:365:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
from extconf.rb:364:in `block in process_recipe'
from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
from extconf.rb:557:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.10.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.10.3/gem_make.out
```

I have seen:

```
gem update --system 3.0.3
```

But don't need this as I already have the latest version of gem.

I have tried:

```
sudo gem install rails --version 4.2.1
```

But this is what throws the above error.

Comment: Which version of MacOS do you have? Please, check answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528115/i386-arch-error-installing-old-scrypt-gem-version-with-os-x-mojave

Comment: The problem is that it fails while installing Nokogiri. You should read the error stack trace since it tells you why it fails. Try `gem install Nokogiri` and see why that gem is failing. Have you tried any of the suggestions in the error?

Comment: seems like you missing built tools for building the native extensions, check this guide pointing out the tools you usually need: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have issues with libxml2

Make sure you have xcodebuild installed:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

Or try to install libxml2 directly via brew:

```
brew install libxml2
```

Also you might try to run

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.3 -- --use-system-libraries
```

Because nokogiri is shipping with it's own libxml2 that's incompatible with some systems

Ref [nokogiri gem installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251494/nokogiri-gem-installation-error)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Installing xcode solved a lot of the issue and dependencies that I needed.