# Bash path to iPhoto library's slideshow

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, slideshow, iphoto

When I click a slideshow called "Unnamed Slideshow" in iPhoto, it tells me it can't find any of the photos. I am trying to delete it but it won't let me, since there are too many pop-up messages. Thus, I was wondering if there was a way to access the diashow using bash to manually remove it. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642147/how-to-remove-files-and-directories-quickly) post. You first need to determine the filepath on your own, then use the pertinent command to either delete the directory or the files.