# I am trying to remove my file "styles" from my local repo using git bash. But the following error is displayed. How to remove my file?

Tags: git, rm

```
India@Abhishek MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Vap class (webcss)
$ mkdir styles
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘styles’: File exists
```

and yet:

```
India@Abhishek MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Vap class (webcss)
$ git rm -r --cached  styles/
fatal: pathspec 'styles/' did not match any files
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove files and directories quickly via terminal (bash shell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642147/how-to-remove-files-and-directories-quickly-via-terminal-bash-shell)

Comment: A thing can exist and not be tracked by Git

Answer (score 0):

The `mkdir` output shows that the *name* `styles` *exists in your working tree*.

The `git rm` output shows that there are no *files in Git's index whose pathname begins with `styles/`*.

These are not inconsistent!  `mkdir` cares only about whether the directory (or folder, if you prefer that term) `styles/` *can be created in the working tree*.  Either that directory (or folder) does in fact already exist, or a file with that name already exists.

The `git rm` command, however, was told to remove *files appearing in Git's index* (`--cached`) whose name *starts with* `styles/`.  So:

- Perhaps `styles` is an existing *file* in your working tree, which may or may not exist in Git's index.  The `mkdir` command cannot create a new directory (folder) with that name because the file is in the way.  Regardless of whether that file is also in Git's index, there are no files whose name *starts with* `styles/`: there is at most one file whose name is just `styles`, not `styles/`.
- Or, perhaps `styles` is an existing *directory* (folder) in your working tree.  Nonetheless, Git's *index*—which I'll talk more about in a moment—does not contain any files whose name starts with `styles/`.  You would get this in several cases.

So, the first thing to  do here is to check whether you have a *file* named `styles`.  If so, that's blocking the existence of a *directory* named `styles` and you will have to do something about the *file*.

We might assume that this is not the problem.  If it were, you probably would not have posted this question.  But maybe it *is* the problem, since you did not mention checking for this first, nor show anything to demonstrate this.  This sort of thing is why writing a good *question* is a good idea.  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  If you write a good *question*, you can often get a short answer. (*cough* )

#### Git's index

Git's index is an important and central construct; understanding what it is, and does for you and Git, is almost as necessary as understanding what a Git *commit* is and does for you and Git.  The index is so important—and/or so poorly named—that it has *three* names in Git:

- *index*, which we have already seen a few times, and which has no apparent meaning;
- *staging area*, which is mainly how you *use* the index: to "stage" files for commit; and
- *cache*.

The last term is somewhat obsolete, but still pops up in places like the `--cached` flag to `git rm`.  Many Git commands accept `--staged` as a synonym for `--cached`, but for some reason, `git rm` still doesn't.

The short and easy to remember description of the index—which is slightly incomplete, as it misses out on the index's role in *merge conflicts*—is that it *holds your proposed next commit*.

That is, when working with Git, we start by picking some particular *commit* that Git should extract:

```
git switch master
```

or:

```
git checkout develop
```

or:

```
git switch --detach a123456    # raw hash ID
```

When we do this—that is, when we *check out* any given, existing commit—Git extracts, *from* that commit, the snapshot-of-all-files that are stored *in* that commit.  These stored files are read-only: every Git commit acts like a tar or zip archive of every file, and once made, no part of *any* commit can *ever* be changed (not even by Git itself).  So the files inside them—which are also compressed and *de-duplicated* to save lots of space—have to be extracted into a working area, so that they can now be normal everyday files that you can work on / with.

The *working copies* of each file are stored in what Git calls your *working tree*.  This part of Git is actually really simple and straightforward.  If you download a tarball or zip archive, you have to un-archive it to get the files out.  The same goes for commits: you have to have Git un-archive them, to get the files out.  The extracted files *go somewhere*, and in Git, that's your *working tree*.  So that explains why there are two copies of every file:

- there's the compressed, de-duplicated copy in the commit; and
- there's a version you can actually *use* in your working tree.

But here's where Git is weird.  For no particularly obvious reason, Git keeps a *third* copy of each file.<sup>1</sup>  The third copy that Git keeps is *in* the compressed-and-de-duplicated format, so when it's files that just came out of some commit, they *don't take any space*,<sup>2</sup> and the obvious objection to keeping a third copy kind of vanishes.

This extra index, or *staged*, copy is *what Git will put into the next commit you make*.  So now you work merrily<sup>3</sup> away in your working tree, fixing bugs, adding features, doing whatever it is you may be doing.  Once you're ready, you must run `git add`.  Why do you have to run `git add` so much?  Because of Git's index, aka *staging area*.  The `git add` step tells Git: *Read the working tree copy.  Compress it.  De-duplicate it.  Stick that compressed, de-duplicated file into your index/staging-area, ready to go into the **next** commit.*  And so, Git does that, and now the index / staging-area has the updated file, which—except for being in Git's format—matches the *working tree* copy now, instead of matching the *current commit's* copy.

This, too, is the big secret of `git status`.  When you run `git status`, Git runs two fast `git diff` operations:<sup>4</sup>

- The first one compares the files in the current (or `HEAD`) commit to the files in Git's index / staging-area.  For whatever is *the same* here, Git says nothing about these files.  For whatever is *different* here, Git says that this file is `staged for commit`.
- The second `git diff` compares the files in Git's index to the files in your working tree.  For whatever is *the same* here, Git says nothing.  For whatever is *different* here, Git says `not staged for commit`.

Since you can, in fact, copy a file into Git's index, and then change the file *again*, you can get one file that is both "staged for commit" *and* "not staged for commit".  That just means that the three copies are different.<sup>5</sup>

So this all shows us how Git's index works: **The index holds the proposed next commit.**  By running `git add` or `git rm`, you update the *proposed next commit*.  You can't change the contents of the *current* commit: those are set in stone.  You can, however, change the contents of your working tree—those are just ordinary computer files after all—and you can change the contents of Git's index too.  You use your working tree files to update your index copies.  Commands like `git add -p` use your working tree copy to *partially* update the index copy, getting you into that state where HEAD, index, and working-tree copies are all different.

---

<sup>1</sup>Other version control systems (VCSes) often *do* have something vaguely similar to Git's index, but they *hide it*.  You don't have to know about it.  You can't *use* it directly, like you can use Git's index.  They tend not to have it as a "third copy" as they don't use Git's internal storage format.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, they take a little space for cache and other data, but it's small enough to mostly ignore.  And, as in footnote 1, other VCSes do the same thing here: it's just *hidden*.  Those other VCSes tend not to have the next-commit-able copy *pre-built* the way Git does, though.

<sup>3</sup>Or other adjective of your choice.

<sup>4</sup>They are *fast* because we have Git run them with `--name-only` or `--name-status` internally: they just check to see *is this file different*, without trying to figure out exactly *what* might be different.

<sup>5</sup>Technically, it *can* mean that the working tree copy matches the HEAD-commit copy, and just the index copy is different.  Try adding one line to a file, running `git add`, and then removing the line.  Run `git status` when in this state—with the "put the file back" change not yet `add`-ed—and observe the status.  Then run `git add` again, and observe that both lines talking about this one file *vanish*.  That's because changing the index copy back made *all three* copies match again, because the *working tree* copy matched the HEAD copy.

---

#### Now that you know about the index, we can see some possible problems

Suppose that `styles` *does* exist as a *directory* in your working tree.

Perhaps you just made it just now.  If so, *there are no files in the directory:* it is empty.  (If you're on a Mac and using the Finder, the Finder might create `styles/.DS_Store` at any point, so watch out on macOS.  Other past or future systems might do something similar too.  But this is all beside the main point.)  Even if you've just created a few files *in* that directory, until you run `git add` on them, they *won't be in Git's index*.

There's another, smaller point to note here: Git's index *cannot* hold directory names.<sup>6</sup>  Instead, Git treats a file name like `styles/a.css` as ... a *file* named `styles/a.css`, complete with forward slash.  This is true even on Windows, where the file's official name is `a.css` in a folder named `styles`, referred to as `styles\a.css`: Git's index *still* holds `styles/a.css` as the file's *name*.  Git knows how to split up its own long, slash-in-the-middle names into folder and file parts when working with your OS, but the names *in* the index are just big long text strings.  The index's names are always case-sensitive, too: even if your OS says that files `readme.txt` and `README.TXT` and `ReadMe.txT` are "the same file", Git's index insists that these are three different names.<sup>7</sup>

When you run `git rm --cached`, you are telling `git rm` that it should work *only* on files *in Git's index*.  Any files in your working tree should be left alone.  This allows you to remove a file from the index entirely, while leaving it intact in your working tree.  That in turn allows you to make sure that the file *won't* be in the *next commit*, since the index stores your *proposed next commit*.  Just make sure that the file stays out of Git's index, and then make the commit, and now the file *isn't in the new commit* and you're all set.

---

<sup>6</sup>There's no good technical reason for this.  It just doesn't.  This might get fixed in some future Git version, maybe.

<sup>7</sup>This causes endless headaches on typical macOS and Windows systems.  It's still the Right Thing to Do, because those differently-named files can and do get created on Linux systems, and then stored into Git repositories, after which there's a problem.  The index should do what it does do now; it's the tooling *around* the index that needs improvement.

---

#### Submodules

The last special wrinkle here occurs with *submodules*.

A Git submodule is Git's way of storing a *reference to* some other Git repository.  Git will utterly refuse to store an actual repository inside another repository (for good and valid reasons).  So if:

```
path/to
```

is a directory (or folder) `path` containing a directory (or folder) `to` in your working tree, and `path/to/sub` is also a directory/folder and `path/to/sub/.git` exists and refers to a Git repository, then `path/to/sub/` is the *working tree* for that other Git repository.

If, at the same time, `.git` here, where `path/to/` exists, exists and refers to a Git repository, then *this* is the working tree of *this* repository.  So we have "nested repositories": this repository, in `path/to/`, seems to contain another repository, `path/to/sub`.

But Git forbids this.  A repository literally cannot contain another repository.  Git resolves the tension here by decreeing that `path/to/sub` is, in *this* repository, to be treated as what Git calls a *gitlink*.

A gitlink is simply a special "file" of type "gitlink".<sup>8</sup>  Git combines this with an entry in a file named `.gitmodules` to form a submodule.  The submodule just tells the "outer" Git: *Make an empty directory here, and later, do a `git clone` and `git checkout` inside the directory.*

If you have a `styles` *gitlink*, then, Git will have created an empty directory named `styles`.  The directory itself will not be filled in unless and until some other Git repository is created—by you, or by Git; this part does not matter—*in* that directory.  Once you or Git *do* create such a Git directory, the *outer* Git will refuse to put anything other than the special gitlink `styles` entry into its index.  There will therefore never be any `styles/` *files* to remove.  Commits you make *in* the outer Git repository, while `styles` in the outer Git's index is this gitlink, will just hold the gitlink.<sup>9</sup>

Hence, any attempt to remove any files named `styles/whatever` are going to fail: the existence of the `styles` gitlink in this Git's index blocks the existence of any `styles/whatever` files in this Git's index.

If you don't want the submodule-ness, you must *remove* the gitlink (and typically you want to remove the `.gitmodules` entry as well at this time) and make a new commit.  You can, before you make the new commit, *also* then *add* the files from the submodule's working tree—after moving or removing the `.git` that makes the outer Git treat the inner one as a submodule, though for sanity's sake I'd recommend de-submodule-ing as one commit, then adding stuff in as a second commit.  But you only want *any* of this if you really do want to eliminate the submodule.

(Do you want that?  I don't know!  "But it is also said: Do not meddle in the affairs of wizards, for they are subtle and quick to anger.  The choice is yours...")

---

<sup>8</sup>A gitlink is an index or tree entry with `mode 160000`.  This is essentially `mode 120000|040000`.  Regular files are mode `100755` or 100644`.`  120000`is a symbolic link, and`040000`is reserved for`tree`.  Tree IDs are not allowed to appear in the index, at least not at this particular level.  That's why footnote 6 is somewhat puzzling.  If you manage to shove a` mode 040000`entry *into* the index, though, some part of Git's index-handling code winds up converting it to a`mode 160000` entry, and everything goes rather haywire.

<sup>9</sup>The "value" associated with that gitlink will be a commit hash ID.  This represents the hash ID that the *outer* Git should use when it runs:

```
(cd styles && git checkout $hash)
```

You update that outer Git index's gitlink hash ID by:

- entering the inner, or submodule, repository (`cd styles`);
- using Git commands to select, or even create, a commit, such that the desired commit *is* the `HEAD` commit in the submodule;
- leaving the submodule to return back to the so-called *superproject*, where the gitlink exists: this is the outer Git; and
- running `git add` to make the superproject read the hash ID from the submodule and update it in the superproject's index.